# vue watch handler called without actual changes

Tags: vue.js

In this [codepen](https://codepen.io/pmorch/pen/JQNLdm) have a counter that can be incremented with a "incr" link.

I now have a computed property and a watch:

```
computed: {
  test() {
    let unused = this.counter;
    return [42];
  }
},
watch: {
  test(val, old) {

    // Should I avoid firing when nothing actually changed
    // by implementiong my own poor-man's change detection?
    //
    // if (JSON.stringify(newVal) == JSON.stringify(oldVal))
    //   return;

    console.log(
      'test changed',
      val,
      old
    );
  }
}
```

A contrived example perhaps, but in reality this is a calculation where the real data is reduced (in a vuex getter) and most-often, the reduced data doesn't change even when some of the data changes.

*Edited to add more detail*: The data in the vuex `store` is normalized. We're also using [vue-grid-layout](https://github.com/jbaysolutions/vue-grid-layout) that expects its `layout`property in a [certain](https://github.com/jbaysolutions/vue-grid-layout#usage) non-normalized format. So we have a `gridLayout` getter that does the vuex -> vue-grid-layout tranform. Watching this gridLayout getter fires even when the resulting gridLayout doesn't actually change, but other details do, such as names and other irrelevant-to-vue-grid-layout object keys in the vuex store.

Now in the above example, when `this.counter` changes, the watch on `test` fires too, even though the `newVal` and `oldVal` are "the same". They aren't `==` or `===` mind you, but "the same" as in `JSON.stringify(newVal) == JSON.stringify(oldVal)`.

Is there any way to have my `watch` fire only when there are actual changes? Actually comparing `JSON.stringify()` seems inefficient to me, but I'm  worried about performance problems as my project grows as my watch could do expensive operations and I want to ensure I'm not missing something.

Comment: Can you give a bit more intent around what you will be using the watcher for? Depending on what you are attempting to do it may be able to be addressed in your architecture decisions. I have created a LARGE enterprise SPA with vue and I ended up removing most getters due to performance reasons and ended up moving them into a library of mixins to be called contextually as opposed to when the underlying state object is updated.

Comment: @TimWickstrom: I've updated the question to add more detail as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Vue.js documentation computed properties are reevaluated when ever a reactive dependency is changed.

In your case the reactive dependency is `this.counter`

You can achieve the same result by invoking a method as opposed to a computed property.

Just change up your component architecture:

```
data () {
  return: {
    counter: 0,
    obj: {},
    output: null
  }
},
watch: {
  counter(val, old) {
    // Alternatively you could remove your method and do something here if it is small
    this.test(val);
  },
  // Deep watcher
  obj: {
    handler: function (val, oldVal) {
        console.log(val);
        console.log(oldVal);
        this.test(val);
    },
    deep: true
},
  }
},
methods: {
  test() {
    let unused = this.counter;
    if (something changed)
      this.output = [42];
    }
  }
}
```

Now in your template (or other computed properties) `output` is reactive

Read more: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods

Comment: And by "if (something changed) {}" I guess you mean implementing my own actual change detection. Isn't that exactly equivalent to my test for `JSON.stringify(newVal) == JSON.stringify(oldVal)` in the watch?

Comment: Yes, however the fundamental difference here is you are removing the Vue computed property and just watching for changes and as you said handling the logic yourself in a method therefore removing the unnecessary computed property. This will remove the overhead of one observable.

Comment: Also, if what you are actually watching is an array or object you may need to add a deep watcher. see updated example. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch

Comment: I'll accept your answer primarily because of the "Read More" link. My problem is the watcher firing too often, not too seldom. `deep: true` doesn't make it fire less often in my experiments. I'll do the JSON.stringify comparison to reduce the false watcher diffs.

Comment: I'll accept your answer primarily because of the "Read More" link. My problem is the watcher firing too often, not too seldom. `deep: true` doesn't make it fire less often in my experiments. I'll do the JSON.stringify comparison to reduce the false watcher diffs. Thanks for your time, @TimWickstrom.

Comment: Another note on this topic you can watch nested value like this: `'obj.my.nested.value' (current, old) { ... }` not sure if that will better achieve your desired result. You will most likely want to use the $set() method to trigger reactivity. That way you can watch for the actual change on your object, not just the "counter"